# Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: java, maven, java-home

I am trying to get maven installation to work but I am always getting this error

> C:\Windows\System32>mvn --version
>   Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
>   JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51;"
>   Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
>   location of your Java installation.

I know that the error says every thing but I have tried everything here. I have the following setting:

System Variables:

**M2_HOME:**   C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.3

**M2:**         %M2_HOME%\bin

**JAVA_HOME:**  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51

I added the whole path maybe it is interested someone. please take a look at the last part.

**Path:**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;%M2%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

**Path interested part:**

```
%M2%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

I have tried it by deleting the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` too but it does not work since I have this path by the SDK installation at the start of the path  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin`

I have tried to add the setting to the user variables and it does not work.

Comment: what is M2 and M2_HOME ?

Comment: @Kushal those are Maven's Envars

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45182761/2849146

Answer (score 6):

> JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51;"

Maven says that there is a semi-colon after the directory name in the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Remove the semi-colon.

Comment: There is no semi-colon but I had it before. I had just to restart my cmd it works now. `

Comment: aye, if you change a system variable, always restart cmd :-)

Comment: @MrPencil Yes, because the command prompt unfortunately doesn't pick up changes to the environment variables immediately - you have to re-open the command prompt.

Comment: Or (at least if you are using bash), you can run the `source` command on your `.bashrc` file to reload the environment variables in that file.

Answer (score 0):

you shoud have both maven and java home defined in the same System Variable ...

Answer (score 0):

Try Rename **M2_HOME** at **MAVEN_HOME**
Also change **M2**: *%MAVEN_HOME%*\bin

Answer (score 0):

For me, the trick is to close and open another CMD window, to check if ir worked