# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory:

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have set `JAVA_HOME` in my system `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_
131\bin;` and I am trying to run cordova command( cordova build ) on command prompt, but I'm getting the error bellow. I have tried all the ways, but not able to resolve this issue:

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_ 131\bin;

Please, set the `JAVA_HOME` variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` should be upto `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_ 131` only

Comment: I removed still am getting the same error

Comment: after changing variable you need to restart command line..also remove double quotes at start and end of variable

Comment: Search for something like [Setting and getting windows environment variables from the command prompt](https://superuser.com/q/79612/77079) to find how to set and check environment variables.

Comment: Yes even I restarted my system as well

Comment: also remove double quotes from start and end of variable..

Comment: nothing is there about semi colon my command prompt shows path like C:\Users>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131;

Comment: remove semicolon also from path

Comment: **your `JAVA_HOME` value should be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_ 131` and make sure you've valid installation of java in same path**

Comment: Its working fine but am getting another errorFAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/
3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Comment: add this error in question in readable format...

Comment: I received this error because of my JDK version was older, than the JRE installed on my machine. Upgrading the JDK to the same version as the JRE resolved this problem.

Comment: For those who are facing the issue in IntelliJ IDE:
I removed \bin but addititionally I had to restart (invalidate caches or opening a new terminal did not meet the demand) my IDE (IntelliJ) until the new value of the env variable was used. Then it was working as expected.

Answer (score 297):

You should set it with **`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_12`**.

**`\bin`** is not required.

Comment: Yes i had open.

Comment: For Linux, something like that is needed: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/`

Comment: how do I know which version of jre I have installed (I'm getting this error in react native app)

Answer (score 83):

`JAVA_HOME` should point to the home jdk directory, and not to `jdk/bin` directory.

You need to set the `JAVA_HOME` like this:

```
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"
```

Comment: In my case the environment variable had wrong path
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_311
Actual java path was C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_321

Answer (score 42):

Remove the `\bin`, and also remove the `;` at the end. After restart the cmd and run.

Comment: Your comment saved my life. Thanks. Added semi colon at the end which leads to endless search in google. After removing the semi colon at the end its works like charm. Thanks

Comment: Your answer is the correct answer. Even after I removed \bin , I got error because of ";".

Comment: Removing semicolon is the trick

Comment: How to remove semi colon

Comment: This man save me :D

Answer (score 39):

On **linux** and **mac**:

1. To find the path `java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'java.home'`
2. result e.g. `java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`
3. copy: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`
4. Add line in your config bash file (e.g.`~/.zshrc`): `export JAVA_HOME=<resultFirstStep>`
5. Be sure and run source ~/.zshrc (or .bashrc, etc.)

Comment: Also worked for Mac

Answer (score 31):

Try the following:

- Remove `\bin` from `JAVA_HOME` path.
- Open new command line window.
- Run your command as an administrator.

Comment: When setting up React Native, I had to remove `\bin` from the JAVA_HOME path.

Answer (score 21):

JAVA_HOME should be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172` don't include semi-colon(;) or bin in path. Any jdk version above 7 will work. Also, you need to re-start the cmd

Answer (score 20):

On Window 10, the problem was with the semicolon `;`.

Go to `edit the system environment variables` and delete the semicolon at the end of `JAVA_HOME` value `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144`

In other words, convert this `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_12;` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_12`

You might have to delete your entry in the Windows Dialog and create a new one. If you ever had multiple entries and get the bigger [Form view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XNz3.png), Windows automatically inserts a `;` at the end of each entry, even if you only have one entry left.

Answer (score 13):

set **JAVA_HOME** as **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172**

do not use semicolon ";" with above JAVA_HOME value

To verify that it is correctly set, Go to **command prompt** check for C:.......>**sdkmanager --list**

a complete list will appear that will let you now that it is successfully saved.

else it will show error that JAVA_HOME path is not correctly set.

Answer (score 8):

Please remove /bin and even semi colon ; from JAVA_HOME to resolve.

Answer (score 8):

Change JAVA_HOME in Environment variable
to this

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr

and since Electric Eel use jbr copy jbr file and replace it into jre then restart ur pc. It worked for me after days of tedious try and error days

Answer (score 7):

First try removing the '\bin' from the path and set the home directory JAVA_HOME as below:
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131

**Second Update System PATH:**

1. In “Environment Variables” window under “System variables” select Path
2. Click on “Edit…”
3. In “Edit environment variable” window click “New”
4. Type in  %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Third restart your docker.

Refer to the [link](https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10) for setting the java path in windows.

Answer (score 6):

If you have updated android studio (2023), then this will surely work for you:

Copy the path of jbr:

---

> `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr`

---

and then under system variables click on new, type JAVA_HOME in the first box and in the second box paste the path of jbr.

Answer (score 5):

While copying the JDK PATH, exclude \bin folder in it.

e.g.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2

your path should look like blow, you just need to edit it and remove \bin folder

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin

Answer (score 4):

After setting the JAVA_HOME variable, run android studio as administrator

Answer (score 4):

You need to set with only C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_12.

And check with using new cmd. It will be updated

Answer (score 4):

I found this while googling the issue with android licences when installing Flutter.

For *Linux*, update Your `~/.bashrc` (or other shell config) file by adding this line at the end:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/android-studio/jre
```

**Note:** I installed Android studio by following the [official installation guide for Linux (link)](https://developer.android.com/studio/install#linux).

For *Windows*, use the android studio's path to the `jre` directory and update the environment variable with the right value.

Then, run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and press `y` to review the licences which are not accepted.
Press `y` for each of the licences. It will ask `Accept? (y/N):` at the end of the license file.
After You accept all unaccepted licences, You should see:

```
All SDK package licenses accepted
```

Answer (score 3):

Check for duplicate entries of `JAVA_HOME` in system variables.

In my case none of the above answers worked but I had two entries for `JAVA_HOME` and removing one worked.

Comment: would you add more details ?

Answer (score 2):

i think you need to remove the ';' from the end of the java path.

Comment: That didn't work, When setting the JAVA_HOME, you should not include the /bin. If you are setting it to the path only you should include the bin

Answer (score 1):

### I was using `jenv`

In my case, I was using jenv but did not set the java version, so the path that jenv was pointing actually a Java installation.

When I ran `echo $JAVA_HOME`, it showed `/Users/username/.jenv/versions/system`, and there was no such file or directory.

### Set a version of java

I just had to do `jenv global 15` **or** `jenv local 15`, to specify what version I wanted to actually use, and `JAVA_HOME` changed when I re-ran `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue after many years using java with AS.
Might help someone to just restart android studio after following the instructions above.

1. Set `JAVA_HOME` to the destination of your java installation or file
2. Don't use /bin in your path
3. **Important**: Restart android studio. (Not restart and invalidate cache). Close AS down and restart.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you installed JDK and then set the path to it. If you have not installed it, you can download and install it from here:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 the `;` is automarically added.
In order to remove this when opening the edit environmental variable window, press the `Edit Text...` and then you will be able to remove the `;` at the end.

After that the `flutter doctor --android-licenses` worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11 some applications require you to set both the **`JAVA_HOME variable`** and include **`Path to JDK Bin Directory`**.

In this case, you need to edit both *Java Home* and the *Path* on the `User variables` and `System Variables`. System variables/User variables don't need the \bin reference but the Path needs the *\bin* reference

**Setting JAVA_HOME**

Simply copy-paste the file path to the JDK folder **`exluding \bin`** part:

*`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21.0.1`*

[image]

**Setting the Path**

You need to **`include \bin reference`** part:

`%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

[image]

`%JAVA_HOME%` points to the above variable file path i.e. *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21.0.1* and then `\bin` is appended at the end.

**Confirmation**

To confirm it has been set correctly, restart Android Studio or CMD and type this command on the terminal:

```
java -version
```

You should see this this message:

> java version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17 LTS Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
> (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build
> 21.0.1+12-LTS-29, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score -1):

i have set like this in vs code for project.its working for me

```
JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_321.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Comment: this answer is not helping to understand why there was an error in the windows system/user environment variables. This is very specific to the internals of VSCode...