# Android development environment set up issue came while trying to run react native app

Tags: react-native, cmd, android-emulator

I am currently trying to run react native application but I am getting this error in windows 10.

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251;

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:630:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:648:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\User\Desktop\crate\crate\code\mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\User\Desktop\crate\crate\code\mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:179:41)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\crate\crate\code\mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:133:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\User\Desktop\crate\crate\code\mobile\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:182:9)
```

I already install java and its working like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu1uE.png)

Also, I run emulator before using this code react-native run-android like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTRd8.png)
it also giving me this error but the emulator working.

```
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
```

What the wrong move that I did in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the same question at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182717/java-home-is-set-to-an-invalid-directory). Edit your environmental variable.

1. Go to User Variables and Edit the path and add %JAVA_HOME%\bin.
2. Now in your system variable environments: edit the path and click new and add this C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin
3. Again in system variable environment click on the path and click on new add this line C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
4. Now save and restart your system. this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the JAVA_HOME environment variable that will be called when running react native android build.

[Setup guide for JAVA_HOME.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html)