# Got any error while installing Android studio on windows 10

Tags: android, flutter, java-home

JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

How to solve this problem??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA\_HOME is set to an invalid directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182717/java-home-is-set-to-an-invalid-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicity download and define the jdk version to be used in the code for running the flutter app.

I also faced the similar issue and below solutions works for me:

Install jdk 11 and add path to `gradle.properties` file

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.11
```

[image]

Comment: Its always a good idea to explain WHY your answer works and not just give an answer for someone to blindly follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks , I will edit the  answer with explanation and try to follow this in future

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your JAVA_HOME is not set correctly.
-> It is essential to set the java path when working on android.
so, Please find these steps below.

1. Go to system properties -> Advance -> Environment Variables ( or just type ENV in search )

   [image]
2. Click new on system variables
   [image]
3. Add variable name as "JAVA_HOME" and Variable value will be the directory of java sdk
   // (do go to bin folder just java folder)

[image]

4. click on path in system variables

[image]

5. Then add new variable as "%JAVA_HOME%\bin

[image]

Now I hope your issue will be fixed.

Comment: do you work on Dell Latitude 7320 13.3? ;-)