# Problem with Android Environment setup in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am running React Native app on MacBook M1 chip, I have already set up the environment [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4j0L.png), but when I type NPM RUN ANDROID, the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyFYo.png) kept showing, please help me out, Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA\_HOME is set to an invalid directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182717/java-home-is-set-to-an-invalid-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Please check path

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/yourUsername/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

please check [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)