# Installing Java to Another Location on Centos 7

Tags: java, installation

I installed java before and i am running java applications on Centos, it is located at /usr/bin/java.
For some other reason i want to install it to another location, let's say /myDirectory/java
I downloaded java jdk as tar file and extract it to /myDirectory this directory then i set JAVA_HOME accordingly.

The problem is i can't start the applications anymore, the log says :

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /myDirectory/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Is it because i had a prior installation? How do i achive this?
Any help would be aprreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182717

Comment: Well, i am trying to change the JAVA_HOME, for a second and seperate installation of java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA\_HOME is set to an invalid directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182717/java-home-is-set-to-an-invalid-directory)

Answer (score 0):

> `ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /myDirectory/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java`

Your error suggests you set `JAVA_HOME` to the path of the `java` binary, but `JAVA_HOME` must point to the JDK directory, not the binary, i.e. `JAVA_HOME=/myDirectory/jdk1.8.0_181`, without `/bin/java`.

Comment: Hello, actually i already tried that one too, same error.

Comment: which tar did you download? can you include in your question what is inside your jdk directory (`ls /myDirectory/jdk1.8.0_181`)?